# fread a lot slower for downloads than readfile

Tags: php, download, fopen, readfile

I'm serving downloads from a URL to my users through a PHP script. When using `readfile()` I get the maximum download speed my connection can support (about 2.5MB/s) however when I use the `fopen, fread, fclose` route the download speed is very, very slow (about 1-2KB/s).

Here's my code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $filesize);
ob_clean();
flush();

$file = fopen($url, 'rb');

while(!feof($file)) {
    echo fread($file, 2014);
}
```

and the readfile code is simply `readfile($link);`.

I can't just use the `readfile()` function because of two reasons, one is I want to restrict the users download speed (which I can do with `fread` by only reading so much data) and I also want to track how much a user is downloading (I can do this with `readfile()` but it doesn't count partial downloads).

Does anyone know why this might be happening or how I can fix it? As far as I know `readfile()` is just a wrapper for `fopen, fread and fclose` so I don't get what's going wrong.

Edit: Ended up going with cURL for this.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $rdLink,
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
    CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => 'readResponse'
);
curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);

if(!curl_exec($curl)) {
    header('Location: http://whatever.com');
    exit;
}
curl_close($curl);

function readResponse($ch, $data) {
    $length = mb_strlen($data, '8bit');

    echo $data;

    return $length;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need output buffering? Try `ob_end_flush();`

Comment: I'm not sure, I got this code from somewhere else and it had output buffering. Where should I put `ob_end_flush();`?

Comment: Put it anywhere before you start writing.

Comment: What happens if you increase the length parameter of fread (the 2014 in your example)? And by the way what is the size of your file?

Comment: Nothing, the length parameter is already more than what the corresponding download speed should be. The size of the file is about 100mb.

Comment: @JamesDawson You wrote "_the length parameter is already more than what the corresponding download speed should be_"; what does that mean? Does your real code have a sleep inside the while() loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [stream_context_create()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) and [stream_get_contents()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php)

```
$context = stream_context_create();
$file = fopen($url, 'rb', FALSE, $context);
while(!feof($file))
{
    //usleep(1000000);
    echo stream_get_contents($file, 2014);
}
```

You could also try making the file read length larger and putting in a usleep() to slow execution.
The stream functions seem to be recommended over fread for the latest version of PHP anyway.
You might want to also prepend an @ in front of the fread() or stream_get_contents() to suppress any errors, at least in production. Without it, and a little mishap, and you have a corrupted file.

Comment: Is this a guess, or is there are a reason it should be faster? I'd love to see some benchmarks of the alternatives.

Comment: This needs some explanation. If stream_get_contents is faster, then why does fread not do what stream_get_contents does?

Comment: That was based on knowing that stream_get_contents() does not timeout and handles what it knows it can based on the conditions of the server. I just tried each with a large file without a read length and the fread timed out resulting in a internal server error and the stream_get_contents worked. But with the read length of 2014 both averaged around the same execution time.
I wanted my comment to be up with the others, but I do not get a 'Add Comment' button. After your reply was the first time it appeared, but only for this block.

Comment: This is the solution to the problem, however I ended up going with a different approach using cURL and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`, which I'll edit into the post. cURL lets me easily add HTTP range headers to the request. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can also add HTTP readers when you start stream_context_create(). Look at the documentation. It should work the same way. Either way, I just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be buffering (or perhaps even rate-limiting) somewhere in PHP or Apache. Try changing:

```
while(!feof($file)) {
   echo fread($file, 2014);
}
```

To:

```
while(!feof($file)) {
   $s=fread($file, 2014);
   if($s===false)break;  //Crude
   echo $s;
   @ob_flush();@flush();
}
```

(The `@` prefix is because they might complain about empty buffers.)

As mr.freshwater said, you ought to have error-checking on your `fread` call, so I've added something basic above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is 2014. OS gets 4096 byte data portion very fast then others. But if you write 2014, then OS tries to read data from file by one byte to calculate it. That's why it takes so long time. Change 2014 to 4096