# How to download large files with PHP?

Tags: php, audio, video, download

I spent a week to find right answer on this question. '*Right*' I mean absolutely conform to existing web-standards, reliable and performance effective. Finally, I've found the solution.

All what I've found on StackOverflow ([Downloading large files reliably in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597159/downloading-large-files-reliably-in-php), [How to download large files through PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527811/how-to-download-large-files-through-php-script)) is not works for me:

1. Both solutions are not support of range requests. It makes them not working for video and audio streaming and download resuming;
2. All examples have nothing about caching and performance;

PHP 7.0 code tested with desktop versions of Chrome, Safari, Opera and Firefox. Vivaldi test was not successful.

Comment: If you want a right answer explain that what do you mean by large? 100MB, 1GB, 10GB, 100GB, 1TB, 1PB?

Comment: Large means more than PHP memory size. I've tested it with 800Mb max.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download large files through PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527811/how-to-download-large-files-through-php-script)

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I tried to use code from your reference. It's not works for audio and video.

Comment: I don't really get this question. You're asking for a method to send files in PHP that is not described in the 19 answers you've linked? What'd be the point? Why don't you, instead, share the code you have and describe the specific problem you're facing so you can get it fixed?

Comment: "absolutely conform to existing web-standards, reliable" - and then you use **error suppression**. Oh the irony. This is poorly-written code that should not be posted.

Comment: Sorry, but my goal was to show simple solution that works. It works. I hope my example will be useful for people who (like me) read all previous 19 answers but didn't get working code. I did remove all error suppression from code (see my comment below) but don't ask me to change spaces to tabs, please ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
const STDOUT_CHUNK_SIZE = 128 * 1024; // Buffer size to send data to browser. MUST be less then 1/3 of PHP memory size
const CACHE_EXP_SEC = 1800;  // Cache expire time is 30 min.

$fileName = "large_video.mp4";
$contentSize = filesize($fileName);
$isAttachment = false;  // false allows to use a file as inline element of web page 

// Parse range request. Browser asks for part of file
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_RANGE"])) {
  list($units, $range) = explode("=", $_SERVER["HTTP_RANGE"], 2);
  if ($units !== "bytes") {
    http_response_code(416); // Requested Range Not Satisfiable
    exit;
  }
  $range = explode(",", $range, 2)[0]; // Get only first range. You can improve this ;)
  list($from, $to) = explode("-", $range, 2);
  $to = empty($to) ? ($contentSize - 1) : min(abs((int)$to), ($contentSize - 1));
  $from = (empty($from) || $to < abs((int)$from)) ? 0 : max(abs((int)$from), 0);
}
else {
  // Request for whole content
  $from = 0;
  $to = $contentSize - 1;
}

// Set response headers
if ($from > 0 || $to < ($contentSize - 1))
{
  http_response_code(206); // Partial Content
  header("Content-Type: video/mp4"));
  header("Content-Range: bytes $from-$to/$contentSize");
  header("Content-Length: " . ($from - $to + 1));
}
else {
  $etag = md5($file);  // Content is immutable but file name can be changed
  if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"]) && trim($_SERVER["HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH"]) === $etag) {
    http_response_code(304); // Not Modified
    setCacheHeaders($etag);
    exit;
  }

  http_response_code(200);  // Ok
  header("Content-Type: video/mp4"));
  header("Content-Length: $contentSize");
  if ($isAttachment) header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
  else header("Content-Disposition: inline");

  header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
  setCacheHeaders($etag);
}

// Send response to client
if ($file = fopen($fileName, "rb")) {
  fseek($file, $from);
  $counter = $from;
  set_time_limit(0);
  while (!feof($file) && $counter <= $to) {
    $bytesToRead = STDOUT_CHUNK_SIZE;
    if ($counter + $bytesToRead > $to) $bytesToRead = $to - $counter + 1;
    $data = fread($file, $bytesToRead);
    $counter += $bytesToRead;
    echo $data;
    flush();
  }
fclose($file);

function setCacheHeaders(string $etag, bool $cacheEnabled = true, bool $public = true)
{
  if ($cacheEnabled) {
    header("ETag: $etag");
    $scope = $public ? "public" : "private";
    $sec = CACHE_EXP_SEC;
    $age = ($sec >= 0) ? ", max-age=$sec, s-maxage=$sec" : "";
    header("Cache-Control: $scope$age, no-transform");
  }
  else header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
}
```

Comment: Why all the @'s?

Comment: Just my style ))) You can omit it.

Comment: I've added some more comments.

Comment: Using `@` isn't simply a case of style, it's a case of hiding errors

Comment: Ok. I see my joke about style was a little bit irrelevant. I did remove all '@'s from code. Unfortunately, PHP is not better tool to build really reliable code. Some standard functions have production even differ from documentation. In my case I just tried to prevent any unpredictable behavior destroying output. Chrome browser is very tolerant for any unexpected responses from server, bur Safari not. I agree, @s are not good solution. It's better to use try-catches or custom error handlers but my goal was to show simple working code.